# Need help to identify this connector on an LED matrix sign

Tags: connector, identification

My step-dad has a matrix board with a control unit:

https://www.ledlightbars.co.uk/led-vehicle-message-signs/haztec-5-9305-99-led-vehicle-message-sign.html

You can plug your laptop into the control box via USB (laptop end) to unknown connection (control box). Then you can program your own signs e.g. "wide load" or "slow down" etc. Does anyone know what the connector is or what cable is needed?

I suspect this may be the cable needed, but I am not certain:

https://www.ledlightbars.co.uk/led-vehicle-message-signs/haztec-5-9301-infosign-programming-software.html

[image: image of device, showing the connector]

Comment: Hi jsotola sorry the device is a control box for a matrix board      https://www.ledlightbars.co.uk/led-vehicle-message-signs/haztec-5-9305-99-led-vehicle-message-sign.html        you plug your laptop into the control box and you can programme in your own signs example...wide load or slow down etc

Comment: Colin - Hi, I hope I have made the question clearer with my edit. Feel free to do any further tidy-up that you want. My brief comment about the question is this: Based on the (blurry) image on the linked page, I don't believe that the signal on that connector is USB (i.e. the programming cable is a USB-to-some-other-interface converter, which is then used on that connector). Even if you can find the connector; even if you can find the interface's electrical standard; how do you plan to actually program new text into the sign, without using the manufacturer's own software that you linked?

Comment: Hi Sam thank you for your edit much appreciated, he has the software already but just not the cable and of course without the cable to connect it to the laptop to program it, he cannot add new signs, I'm not certain thatis the cable all I know is one end is USB and the other goes into that port on my questions picture I've seen them before but I've no idea what they are

Comment: Have you asked ledlightbars.co.uk if they can supply a (replacement?) cable, or if the cable/software you linked works with your sign?

Comment: Hi I have messaged them to enquire as to whether they can supply a cable which will do the job the matrix board was given to my step dad by a friend who had lost the cable

Answer (score 1):

For future reference this connector is a Hirose MQ172 4 pin. Pinout is as follows:

1. 5v
2. D+
3. D-
4. Gnd

Normal USB Standard :)